# Issue with C# & C++ in a Windows 8 application

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have code that uses the Media Foundation Transform to apply effects to a video stream presented in XAML/C#. It is in fact the Media Capture sample supplied by Microsoft. I wanted to use the DirectX Toolkit so I added a reference to it in the C++ application. The build was successful however I faced the following error:

```
warning LNK4197: export 'DllGetActivationFactory' specified multiple times; using first specification 
warning LNK4197: export 'DllCanUnloadNow' specified multiple times; using first specification
warning LNK4197: export 'DllGetActivationFactory' specified multiple times; using      first specification 
warning LNK4197: export 'DllCanUnloadNow' specified multiple times; using first specification
error LNK2005: _DllCanUnloadNow@0 already defined in dllmain.obj 
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

It is described in more detail here:
[Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current Not Found in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893355/windowsstorageapplicationdatacurrent-not-found-in-c)

However after following the steps in that post I faced another error.
When the C# code tries to call the WinRT dll at

```
await m_mediaCaptureMgr.AddEffectAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, "GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect", null);
```

it throws a new exception without any detail. The exception text is

```
System.Exception: Error in the DLL
at Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture.AddEffectAsync(MediaStreamType mediaStreamType, String effectActivationID, IPropertySet effectSettings)
```

All I've done is linked my DLL to the GreyscaleTransform via the compiler without any additional code being invoked yet.

Any thoughts on what could cause this or what is the best way to troubleshoot it?

Many thanks,
Stefan